# How do I log back into the anonymous account that I created when I ran the app again?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

Hi I am a novice developer, I have a guest login question
I created an anonymous account and closed the app
How do I log back into the anonymous account that I created when I ran the app again?

The first time you log in, the creation of an anonymous account works normally
When I quit and log in again, I loaded the [uid] or [idToken] that I saved and logged in
But I get an error

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        AuthStateChanged(this, null);
    }

    void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (auth.CurrentUser != user)
        {
            bool signedIn = user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;

            if (!signedIn && user != null)            
                Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);

            user = auth.CurrentUser;

            if (signedIn)            
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + user.UserId);                

        }
    }

    public void OnClickedLogIn()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();

        if(GetString("idToken") == null)
        {
            auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync was canceled.");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("SignInAnonymouslyAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }

                FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;

                Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                    newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);

                string uid = newUser.UserId;
                SetString("uid", uid, "testKey");

                //토큰저장
                task.Result.TokenAsync(true).ContinueWith(work => {
                    if (work.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("TokenAsync was canceled.");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (work.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("TokenAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                        return;
                    }

                    string idToken = work.Result;                    
                    Debug.Log(task.Result.UserId + "\n" + idToken);                    
                    SetString("idToken", idToken, "testKey");
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("기존로그인");
            string uid = GetString("uid");  **uid & token **
            Debug.Log(uid);
            string token = GetString("idToken");
            Debug.Log(token);           

            auth.SignInWithCustomTokenAsync(token).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("IsCanceled");
                    return;
                }
                if (task.IsFaulted) **<<<-------------- this error occured**
                {
                    Debug.LogError("IsFaulted" + task.Exception);
                    return;
                }
                auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
                AuthStateChanged(this, null);
                Debug.Log("로그인성공" + user.UserId);
            });
        }
    }

    public void OnClickedDelete()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
    }

    public static void SetString(string _key, string _value, string _encryptKey)
    {
        //key 숨기기
        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        byte[] hashData = md5Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key));
        string hashKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashData);

        byte[] secret = md5Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_encryptKey));
        //암호값 바이트 배열에넣기
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_value);
        //값 암호화 3des
        TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.Key = secret;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform xform = des.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] encrypted = xform.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        //암호화배열 변환 읽을수있는문자열로
        string encryptedString = System.Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        //값넣기
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(hashKey, encryptedString);
    }

    public static string GetString(string _key, string _encryptKey = "testKey")
    {
        //key문자열 숨기기
        MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create();
        byte[] hashData = md5Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key));
        string hashKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashData);

        byte[] secret = md5Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_encryptKey));

        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(hashKey))
            return null;

        //암호화된값 검색 및 Base64로 디코드
        string value = PlayerPrefs.GetString(hashKey);
        byte[] bytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(value);

        //암호화된 값 3des로
        TripleDES des = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.Key = secret;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        ICryptoTransform xform = des.CreateDecryptor();
        byte[] decrypted = xform.TransformFinalBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        //암호해제 값 적절한문자열로
        string decryptedString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);

        return decryptedString;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you restart the application, the user's previous identity should automatically be picked up. Your `AuthStateChanged` should automatically fire with a non null user.

Comment: After restart the application, user is null.... i had InitializeFirebase()

Comment: Hmmm...maybe the Unity SDK doesn't auto-persist the token then. If you simply call `auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync()` automatically, does it generate the same UID (that's what other Firebase SDKs do)?

Comment: No, a new account is created. different uid

Comment: Hmmm... in that case I don't know. Most (but not all) Firebase SDKs persist the auth information.

Comment: Thanks a lot has helped